# How to post to timeline after the feature is removed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post

At https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/#other I see that the feature to post to timeline is removed. Will it be possible in a way to post to the timeline after that feature is removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting on own's timeline `/me/feed` is not been removed. Posting on other user's/friend's walls is removed. For latter, you may use [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/) concepts.

You can follow the similar question here: [How to post on a friend's Timeline after the February 2013 migration takes effect?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14190877/how-to-post-on-a-friends-timeline-after-the-february-2013-migration-takes-effec)

Comment: Phew. And can you give me a link to where the `/me/feed` feature is explained? Can't find it..

Comment: Its simple [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). If the answer helped, you can mark this as correct.